# where to find parse.ly API UUID parameter

Tags: api, google-analytics

When making a call to parse.ly it's unclear to me where the UUID comes from. Is this something that needs to be passed to parse.ly at the beginning of a session?
http://www.parsely.com/help/api/recommendations/

Answer (score 0):

It is covered in the section on ["Personalized recommendations"](http://www.parsely.com/help/api/recommendations/#personalized) in the same page. Parse.ly generates a first-party UUID automatically in its JavaScript tracker which is accessible via `PARSELY.config.uuid` after the tracker is loaded. If you leverage the `PARSELY.onload` handler, [as described here](http://www.parsely.com/help/integration/dynamic/#the-onload-handler), you can access `PARSELY.config.uuid` and use it to train recommendation profiles.

If you are doing profile training or recommendation calls server-side, then you'll need to pass that UUID through to your server.

One other option is to leverage the Parse.ly cookie; Parse.ly visitor information is stored in the `_parsely_visitor` cookie set at the domain-level, under the `id` key in the serialized JSON.

Hope that helps. Also note that since Parse.ly is a full-service analytics provider, you can also file a support ticket for help with integration issues.

Comment: I see. Also see the cookie. So if I send the UUID along with the URL canonical parse.ly will return user recommendations. What if it's their 1st page view? User has now browsing data.